# ctrl + drag to wrong swift file

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard, ios9, xcode7

I'm making a project with 3 widgets, now I started working on the 3rd widget, and every time when I drag a button from the story board onto the "todayViewController.swift"it places it in the "todayViewController.swift" of the first widget.
I only need to connect one more button, is there a way to do it without the ctrl+drag method?

Comment: Can you post screenshots? Without seeing how your storyboard is setup, it's hard to picture what could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning the project and restarting xcode after it fixed the issue.